Vlan Communication
I'm trying to ping a pc from vlan 10 to vlan 11 pc but it seems always stops at 192.168.0.1 according to tracert 
router (vlan 10) config :
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN10
 network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.248
 default-router 192.168.0.1
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX152453VZ-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.248
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.10.0.1 255.0.0.0
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
 network 192.168.1.0
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.248 10.10.0.2 
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.248 10.10.0.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end

switch (vlan 10)  config :
Current configuration : 1451 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S1
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10-11
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10-11
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end

router (vlan 11) config :
Current configuration : 1204 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN11
 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.248
 default-router 192.168.1.1
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524U954-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.11
 encapsulation dot1Q 11
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.248
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.10.0.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
 network 192.168.0.0
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.248 10.0.0.1 
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.248 10.10.0.1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end

switch (vlan 11) config:
Current configuration : 1451 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S2
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 11
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 11
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 11
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 11
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 11
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10-11
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10-11
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end


Router 0:
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.10.0.1 255.0.0.0

You shouldn't be wasting 16 million IP addresses on a P2P link. /31 is sufficient.
Router 1:
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.248 10.0.0.1 

That needs to point to 10.10.0.1 instead.
